# What does the word 「いまいった」mean?

Tags: words, colloquial-language, manga

Here is the sentence I found the word.

> わしはむかし丹｛たん｝下｛げ｝段｛だん｝平｛ぺい｝とはちがうんだ　わかってくれ
>
> **いまいった**すじのいい若いのにわしゃあ命｛いのち｝をかけとるんだ　わしの先生命だ！

I have tried searching for some web sites e.g. Jisho.org, dictionary.goo.ne.jp　or weblio.jp but there is no where refer to the meaning of it.

I guess it might be meaning as 'right now' or 'present time' but I have no idea what the word 「いった」means.

Comment: [We don't do translations](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/799/1628).  Please edit your question to include things such as the research you've done, what you think it might mean within the context, grammar that is giving you trouble, etc.

Answer (score 1):

いまいった in the above sentence can be analyzed at least in two ways. The first is much more probable than the second in any context.

> 1. いま (now) + いった (have said)　meaning, as I have said
> 2. いま (now) + いった (have passed away)

Considering the context and a very particular adjective of すじのいい (natural bent), it will be safe for me to determine on the first analysis. This kind of いまいった, even if it is not entered in Japanese dictionaries, is very common in daily conversation, but not in formal written Japanese (compared with いま述べた as mentioned before).

- 「いまいっただろう。お前はおれのいったことを聞いてないのか。」
- 「いまいったようにやりなさい。」
- 「いまいった話には、注意しなさい。」(used as adjective modifier)
- 「いまいった車は、もう売られていない。」(used as adjective modifier)